# Finding the calendar date of an ongoing event when the start-date and weekday are known

Tags: php, mysql, date, schedule, weekday

I'm trying to create a schedule of unique, recurring events that cycle on a weekly basis (each event will have unique identifiers and repeat weekly).

In addition to other information gathered about each event, I will gather the weekday on which each event will take place and the dates (calendar dates) on which the event will begin and end.

An example:

```
Event:       Go to gym    (the event I plan to do once a week)
Day of Week: Sunday       (day of week event will occur (every Sunday))
Start Date:  2014-09-01   (happens to be a Monday)
End Date:    2015-08-31   (...)
```

The purpose is to write a script that takes any multitude of events and their respective weekday/start/end date and recreate a calendar depicting the future calendar dates on which each event will occur.

```
So the first date I should see scheduled to go to the gym will be:
2014-09-07
because this is first Sunday following the start date.
```

To sum it up, I am gathering the weekday of each event as well as the start and end dates. How can I parse these pieces of data into something that spits out a list of the events' future dates of reoccurrence?

Keep in mind that there will be a vast number of events that will occur on different days of the week and have different start/end dates.

Thank you for all who read and respond.

Tried:

```
SQL: grouping, different select statements, and stuff
PHP: stuff, date/time stuff, and stuff stuff
```

Comment: How are the dates stored in the database? Timestamps or dates or...? Please do paste the things you've tried, you might have been in the right direction, but just made some error along the road..

Answer (score 0):

For next event in schedule you could use `strtotime` function:

```
strtotime('2014-09-01 next Sunday');
```

and use returned UNIX time.

But for complete solution of your problem there can be many ways. IMHO, `strtotime` used in `for` cycle can give you a large overhead if calculated on demand. If you store schedule in DB, perhaps it will be easiest solution to generete dates and regenerate them on edit.

In other hand, dates are pain in head so algoritm to calculate all ocasions can be much bigger. You can use intervals calculated from difference of result date from first date if `$firstDate = $startDate` or if event happens every day once a week, then just add 7 days to it.

Post more details or your solution to find mistakes.